# Reading and printing the data between two positions in file with using file.read().find()

Tags: python, printing, find, readfile, txt

I am trying to read and print data between two positions that I found with file.read().find . How can I print them ?

This is the code that I use for found the start and end positions of the data.

```
name = "FEMMeshGmsh.inp"
file = open(name, "r")
text = file.read()
startPosition = text.find("Face9")
print(startPosition)
endPosition = text.find("*",startPosition)
print(endPosition)
```

outputs :

```
72365
73071
```

This is the data that I am trying to print in file :

```
** node loads on shape: Connect:Face9
10,1,0.0000000000000E+00
11,1,0.0000000000000E+00
26,1,0.0000000000000E+00
27,1,0.0000000000000E+00
80,1,6.2500000000000E+01
152,1,0.0000000000000E+00
153,1,0.0000000000000E+00
154,1,0.0000000000000E+00
155,1,6.2500000000000E+01
156,1,6.2500000000000E+01
157,1,6.2500000000000E+01
158,1,6.2500000000000E+01
159,1,0.0000000000000E+00
160,1,0.0000000000000E+00
161,1,0.0000000000000E+00
162,1,6.2500000000000E+01
163,1,6.2500000000000E+01
164,1,6.2500000000000E+01
165,1,6.2500000000000E+01
166,1,6.2500000000000E+01
424,1,1.2500000000000E+02
425,1,1.2500000000000E+02
426,1,1.2500000000000E+02
427,1,1.2500000000000E+02
428,1,1.2500000000000E+02
429,1,1.2500000000000E+02
430,1,1.2500000000000E+02



***********************************************************
```

I used file.read().find() for taking the positions. And I assigned them into variable. Start and end. I should use "Face9" and "*" parameters to reach the data

Comment: Use a slice: `print(text[startPosition:endPosition])`

Comment: `file.read().find()` can't be used for this, because you can't call it multiple times. The first time will read the entire file, and the second call will start reading from the end (unless you use `file.seek(0)` between the calls to rewind).